# Create and Submit numbered changelist from Jenkins to Perforce

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I want to create a numbered changelist in my Jenkins job, add files to that changelist and submit that changelist.
In jenkins I can get changelist number by using `%P4_CHANGELIST%`.
I am adding file to changelist like this `p4 edit //abc/xyz.txt -c %P4_CHANGELIST%`.
And submitting like this `p4 submit -c %P4_CHANGELIST%`.
While submitting output says that changelist number is already commited.
`Change 100378 is already committed`.
Basically, I need a numbered changelist which is not already taken so that I can add my files to this numbered changelist and submit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mix up things.
Jenkins gives you the latest change that led to the build with `%P4_CHANGELIST%`.
But with the perforce command `p4 submit -c changenumber` you tell perforce to submit a (yet unsubmitted) change. That cannot work.

Obviously you want to submit a completely new change.
For that you don't need to refer to any existent changenumber.
You just do:

```
p4 edit //abc/xyz.txt 
p4 submit -d "description"
```

Comment: This will add to the default changelist. I want to add it to a numbered changelist

Comment: You cannot add to an existing changelist in state "submitted".
What you could do is create a new changelist (with "p4 change") and in the following work on that change.
But the only reason that comes to mind why you would want to do that, is that your JenkinsJob uses a P4CLIENT that is already in use elsewhere. That is not advisable.

Comment: yes P4CLIENT is in use. I'll probably create a new client and do it using the default changelist.